# Is a single or bi-positional indicator better for a binary state?

Tags: toggle

I have a set of entities (notes) whose content can be either visible or hidden, independently for each note.

[image]

[image]

There are two possible states for that property and I was wondering whether it is  generally better to use

- a [toggle switch](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/toggle#with-icons) that will move between the two states with a different icon for each state
- a single icon which, when pressed, will change (the eye in the screenshot above)

**Which one is more natural, from a UX perspective?**

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of other icons nearby, so the eye will probably work OK, as the overall look is more harmonious.

A toggle switch has the advantage that the state can be perceived easier than with an icon, where one has to think about the meaning, at least a little bit.

In your situation I'd try for the toggle switch with different icons.